# Problem loading VTK window into PyQT Window

Tags: python, pyqt4, vtk

I'm tearing my hair out with a problem with VTK and PyQt4. I have an interface that has two tabs in it, one will house the VTK window and the other graphs.

The code for ui_Test which sets up the interface is as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tabWidget"))
        self.tab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab"))
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.tab)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout_2"))
        self.vtkLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vtkLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("vtkLayout"))
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.vtkLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.tab_2 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab_2"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 31))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 1", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 2", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And the main window code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from vtk import vtkSphereSource,vtkRenderer,vtkColorTransferFunction,vtkPoints,vtkCellArray,vtkUnsignedCharArray,vtkPolygon,vtkPolyData,VTK_MAJOR_VERSION,vtkPolyDataMapper,vtkActor,vtkProperty,vtkScalarBarActor
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from vtk.qt4.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor
import ui_Test 
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow,ui_Test.Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


        self.vtkWidget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor(self)
        self.vtkLayout.addWidget(self.vtkWidget)

        self.ren = vtkRenderer()
        self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(self.ren)
        self.iren = self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().GetInteractor()

        # Create source
        source = vtkSphereSource()
        source.SetCenter(0, 0, 0)
        source.SetRadius(5.0)

        # Create a mapper
        mapper = vtkPolyDataMapper()
        mapper.SetInputConnection(source.GetOutputPort())

        # Create an actor
        actor = vtkActor()
        actor.SetMapper(mapper)

        self.ren.AddActor(actor)

        self.ren.ResetCamera()




        self.iren.Initialize()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The problem is that when this runs it throughs errors in the VTK error log window and nothing shows on the tab. The error looks something like this:

ERROR: In C:\VPP\standalone-build\VTK-source\Rendering\OpenGL2\vtkShaderProgram.cxx, line 431
vtkShaderProgram (0000016142650060):

ERROR: In C:\VPP\standalone-build\VTK-source\Rendering\OpenGL2\vtkWin32OpenGLRenderWindow.cxx, line 769
vtkWin32OpenGLRenderWindow (00000161425DD820): failed to get valid pixel format.

ERROR: In C:\VPP\standalone-build\VTK-source\Rendering\OpenGL2\vtkOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx, line 785
vtkWin32OpenGLRenderWindow (00000161425DD820): GLEW could not be initialized.

ERROR: In C:\VPP\standalone-build\VTK-source\Rendering\OpenGL2\vtkShaderProgram.cxx, line 430
vtkShaderProgram (0000016142650060): 1: #version 120

I won't post the full thing as it is really long! I can make the PyQT VTK examples run so the VTK/PyQT version isn't the problem - I assume it is to do with how I'm adding it to the tab. Any help will be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I'm using PyQt5, everything works without problems.

**main.py**

```
import sys
#from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from vtk import vtkSphereSource,vtkRenderer,vtkColorTransferFunction,vtkPoints,vtkCellArray,vtkUnsignedCharArray,vtkPolygon,vtkPolyData,VTK_MAJOR_VERSION,vtkPolyDataMapper,vtkActor,vtkProperty,vtkScalarBarActor
#from vtk.qt4.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor
from vtk.qt.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor         

import ui_Test 


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, ui_Test.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.vtkWidget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor(self)
        self.vtkLayout.addWidget(self.vtkWidget)

        self.ren = vtkRenderer()
        self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(self.ren)
        self.iren = self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().GetInteractor()

        # Create source
        source = vtkSphereSource()
        source.SetCenter(0, 0, 0)
        source.SetRadius(5.0)

        # Create a mapper
        mapper = vtkPolyDataMapper()
        mapper.SetInputConnection(source.GetOutputPort())

        # Create an actor
        actor = vtkActor()
        actor.SetMapper(mapper)

        self.ren.AddActor(actor)

        self.ren.ResetCamera()

        self.iren.Initialize()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**ui_Test.py**

```
#from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtWidgets.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtWidgets.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtWidgets.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tabWidget"))
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab"))
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout_2"))
        self.vtkLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vtkLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("vtkLayout"))
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.vtkLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab_2"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 31))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 1", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 2", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

[image]

Comment: Good to know - maybe I should just upgrade!